# How can I send notification to users when I update my Sqlite db in Android App?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have an Android app that display products come from SQLite db in a server. I want when I add a new product a notification send to users tell him there is a new product added to app and users don't need to launch the app to receive that notification they only need to internet. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your second to last sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean you should not use FCM?

Comment: edited @Stealth Rabbi

Comment: You should try to clarify more about what you're trying to do and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

FCM would actually be perfect in this case because you can trigger it after a new "sql insert". Another idea could be sending a txt to your users but I'm not sure if your storing their phone number or not.

Comment: Can you give me more details about FCM and i don't want to send message from notification panel i want to send it after insert a new product (like a link) so when user click on this notification it send him to that new product and thanks Mr.@Keheira

Comment: So not sure what your code looks like but you want to do something like the `call function to add item -> After confirmation of added item trigger FCM function - >Notification will be sent out` does that make sense?